# Close a scrollView pragmatically created in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I created a scrollView prgrammatically

extract from .xml file

```
<!-- Spinner -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here .kt code snippet

```
/***************** SCROllL VIEW *****************/
fun showSpinner(show: Boolean) {
    if (linearLayout == null) {
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1)
        if (show) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            ...
            ...
        } else {
            // Close de scrollView
            // TODO: fermer le spinner
            if (linearLayout!! != null) {
                linearLayout!!.visibility == null
            }

            // TODO: Add a frame auround the scroll view to get a better look
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not close, why?

I think the error is in the line "linearLyaout !!. Visibility == null" but I did
seek and find nothing to put me on the way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
linearLayout!!.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: Thanis a lot href.

Comment: After I used View.GONE (which works perfectly) I can't see it again after recreate it!?

Comment: use this code to visible layout `linearLayout!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE`